# more memory allocated on the stack than seems to be needed

Tags: disassembly, stack

Im working on the `bof` challange in http://pwnable.kr/play.php.
the source code has a function `func`:

```
void func(int key){
   char overflowme[32];
   printf("overflow me : ");
   gets(overflowme);    // smash me!
   if(key == 0xcafebabe){
       system("/bin/sh");
   }
   else{
       printf("Nah..\n");
   }
}
```

when disassembling, it starts like this:

```
0000062c <func>:
62c:    55                      push   %ebp
62d:    89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
62f:    83 ec 48                sub    $0x48,%esp
632:    65 a1 14 00 00 00       mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
638:    89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
63b:    31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
63d:    c7 04 24 8c 07 00 00    movl   $0x78c,(%esp)
644:    e8 fc ff ff ff          call   645 <func+0x19>
649:    8d 45 d4                lea    -0x2c(%ebp),%eax
64c:    89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
64f:    e8 fc ff ff ff          call   650 <func+0x24>
654:    81 7d 08 be ba fe ca    cmpl   $0xcafebabe,0x8(%ebp)
        ...
```

the `overflowme` buffer is 32 byte , but instruction `62f` allocates 0x48=72 bytes on the stack, why does it allocates much more memory than it seems to need ?